# Adding extra fields to devise token auth user sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise-token-auth

I have a signup form for devise-token-auth. I would like users to enter a username as well on the signup form. The username column exists in the database but the controller rejects it

```
Unpermitted parameter: :username
```

How can I extend the permitted parameters for signup in devise token auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this works exactly the same as regular devise. The general idea can be found from [this page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)

But specifically, add this to ApplicationController

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  added_attrs = [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation]
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set permitted params in your controller's action. Look this https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html